# The weak restriction of the Jacquet module

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, p-adic-groups

Let $P= MN$ be a parabolic subgroup of a reductive p-adic group $G$, and $(\pi, V)$ is an irreducible, admissible representation of $G$. The Jacquet module is the representation $(\pi_N, V_N)$, where $\pi_N$ is the restriction of $\pi$ on the $M$-invariant subspace $V_N= V/V(N)$, and $V(N)$ is the linear span of $v−\pi(n)v; ~ v\in V,n\in N.$
If $\pi$ is tempered, the weak (= tempered) Jacquet module is $(\pi^w_N, V^w_N)$, where $V^w_N$ is the maximal tempered quotient of $V_N$. Using the character if $\Theta$ is the character of $\pi$, then $\Theta^w_M$ is the character of $\pi^w_N$(following: Harish-Chandra it is the weak constant term of $\Theta$ along $P$)

Now acoording to J.Arthur, if $\sigma$ is a discrite series of $M$  there is a bijection between the set of irreducible constituents of the representation induced by $\sigma$ denoted $Ind^G_M(
\sigma)$ and the set of irreducible representations of the Knapp-Stein R-group $R_\sigma$. If in addition $L$ is a Levi subgroup of $G$, with split component $A_L$ and $\mathcal{a}_L$ is the Lie algebras of $A_L$, containing $M$ and satisfies the Compatibility Condition
of Arthur, "CCA" ( that: $\mathcal{a}_L \cap\overline{\mathcal{a}^{+}_\sigma}$ contains an open subset of $\mathcal{a}_L$; where $\mathcal{a}^{+}_\sigma$ 
denotes
the positive chamber corresponding to the reduced roots for which the Plancherel measure of $\sigma$ vanishes), then $R^L_\sigma$ is the Knapp-Stein R-group of $Ind^L_M(\sigma)$ and so as at $G$ we obtain another bijection...

My question is: If $L$ is as above but it does not satisfies "CCA", Is $\Theta^w_L = 0$ ??

Thanks in advance